# How to remove leftover space after applying scale modifier in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In this app, I was going to put a scrollable list of composable with each have a size relative to the device screen but then scale down to a few pixel. And I found the best way to keep the layout unchanged and consistent to when it's fullscreen is to make the size of the composable exactly the same as the device screen and then resize it with `scale` modifier

```
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            Surface(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = .2f),
            ) {
                ScreenVisual(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(screenWidth, screenHeight)
                        .scale(.7F)
                )
            }
            Surface(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = .2f),
            ) {
                OtherScreenVisual(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(screenWidth, screenHeight)
                        .scale(.7F)
                )
            }
        }
```

[image]

But then as shown on the image above, there are leftover spaces from the composable after the scale modifier, the question is how to remove those spaces and force each surface to stick with each other

Comment: why not just `screenWidth * 0.7f` instead of using scale?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov if I use that then every size in every widget in that composable will need to be adjusted manually or else the layout will be in a mess.

For simple example, if I use your advice `screenWidth * 0.7f`, then long text wont get resized as well and instead will get wrap into two lines. 

But still, you just gave me an idea, I might try placing scaleFloat as a parameter in composable and multiply each widget size with that scaleFloat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by combining `size`, `requiredSize` and `scale` modifiers.

```
Content(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(width = screenWidth * scale, height = screenHeight * scale)
        .requiredSize(width = screenWidth, height = screenHeight)
        .scale(scale)
)
```

- `size(screenWidth * scale, screenHeight * scale)`
  means that you would reserve just the amount of space that's equals to scaled screen size.
- `requiredSize(screenWidth, screenHeight)` forces to measure and layout content with real screen size, so it will be rendered with normal scale and centred inside that previously defined frame. Of course at that stage the rendered content would be too big for that frame.
- `scale(scale)` would scale the content inside to fit the frame declared with `.size`

You can see that entire content is scaled properly. In this case `Texts` with `30.sp` are scaled down compared to the `Text` on top (that is not scaled in any way).

Entire sample looks like this:

```
Column {
    Text("Text 30sp (for comparison)", fontSize = 30.sp, modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

    Row(Modifier.horizontalScroll(state = rememberScrollState())) {

        Content1(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(width = screenWidth * scale, height = screenHeight * scale)
                .requiredSize(width = screenWidth, height = screenHeight)
                .scale(scale)
        )

        Content2(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(width = screenWidth * scale, height = screenHeight * scale)
                .requiredSize(width = screenWidth, height = screenHeight)
                .scale(scale)
        )
    }
}
```

And example of how the sample `Content1` looks like:

```
@Composable
private fun Content1(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        "Text 30sp",
        fontSize = 30.sp,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Blue)
    )
}

...
```

[image]

Comment: Woah, it actually works, thanks a lot!

Comment: You saved me from some hours searching great!